# Two way binding on React onChange is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onchange, two-way-binding

On the second `<Person/>` component I have props `nameChanged = {this.nameChangeHandler}` where I am using two-way data binding but it is not working I don't think I'm missing anything.
There is no error in the console

```
<div>
    <p onClick={props.click}>My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} Year old!</p>
    <p>{props.children}</p>
    <input type="text" onChange={props.changed}/>
</div>

nameChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.setState = ({
        persons:[
            {name:"Roja", age: 34},
            {name: event.target.value, age: 35},
            {name:"Manu", age: 45}
        ]
    })
}

<Person 
    name = {this.state.persons[1].name} 
    age = {this.state.persons[1].age} 
    click={this.switchNameHandler.bind(this, "SammRad")}
    changed={this.nameChangeHandler}>
        My hobbies are Racing
</Person>
```

[App component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ski3v.png)
[Person component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swe9I.png)

Comment: Try changing your `person` component to `Person`

Comment: Typo: `this.setState = ({` should be `this.setState({` in `nameChangeHandler`.

Comment: ok worked thanks man silly mistake on my side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your `person` component to `Person`, notice the caps. And also, I don't think even then it would compile properly, the component looks weirdly structured, so try this instead.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react'; 

const Person = (props) => 
<Fragment>
    My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} Year old!
    {props.children}
</Fragment>

export default Person;
```

You should always wrap your component's content within a parent component. If you don't have top parent component to act as a wrapper, you can use `Fragment` instead, which is basically an empty component to help you in this situation and allow React to compile, it doesn't even print anything on the HTML.

Also, you should use an IDE that gives you these kind of hints, I suggest using [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: i tried it still not working but thanks for quick answer

Comment: @hunter Can you tell me what's on the error log?

Comment: import React from 'react';

const person = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p onClick={props.click}>My name is {props.name} and I am {props.age} Year old!</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
            <input type="text" onChange={props.changed}/>
        </div>
    )
};
export default  person;

Comment: @hunter you also need to change `person` to `Person` like I mentioned, and make sure the file name is also capitalized and in the correct path.

Comment: i changed the person to Person and import the correct path like you said it is still not working

Comment: I added two pic of the code please check them out

Comment: I think Ajeet figured what might be causing the issue on your post answer. Try that out and let us know if it works.